# What languages have multi-platform support for app developement?

Tags: mobile, multiplatform

I'm going to be building an application that will be used across multiple devices including:

- iOS
- Android
- WinRT (Windows 8 & Window 8 RT)
- Windows Phone 8

I would like to develop the business logic once and use it across all devices, and then develop the UI for each individual device which in turn interfaces with the business logic.  Is there a language that is natively supported across all of these platforms and if so what is it?

<sup>Note:  I'm **NOT** Looking for a all-in-one solution for UI and business logic.  I'm simply trying to develop the logic behind the app that can be re-used if possible by all platforms</sup>

Comment: C/C++ and C# (with MonoTouch/MonoDroid) are basically your options as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx). These are typically coded in C# and can be reused throughout all those platforms.

You will probably also need [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)

Comment: Xamarin seems pretty expensive for full-support, and has limited support for the cheaper options :/

Comment: I've looked, and looked, and looked, and apparently there's nothing else out there.  They do have an indie license that uses their IDE, or their business license ($999 per platform) if you want/need to use Visual Studio.  I'm going to give it a shot, and see how it goes.